# Cannot install wordpress, /wp-admin/install.php, inproper redirection

Tags: redirect, installation

I cannot complete wordpress instalation. I enter all the database parameters and successfully proceed but then it get stucked at /wp-admin/install.php
It says:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> ```
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
> ```
>
> What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I managed it myself, I just erased a htaccess file, there was one of another website in parent folder (I moved it back after installation)